# Java filter numbers from num pad in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

Key code for number 1 is in Java 49 and key code for number 1 from the num pad is 97.
I have a JTextArea and I need to prevent inserting numbers from the numeric pad.

I tried:

- using a DocumentFilter but here I don't get the key code
- using a ActionMap, here I can match the key code but I can't prevent it from adding to the JTextArea text
- the last option is to use KeyListener. I guess I could use KeyListener and a external variable and keep in this variable the data I need but I hope there is a better way to do this.
  I know no direct way to prevent a key to be inserted using KeyListener.

Later edit: when using ActionMap I can't delete the last character because "actionPerformed" is executed before adding the caracter to the JTextArea. I tried this:

```
JTextArea jtf1 = new JTextArea();   
jtf1.getActionMap().put("handleReplaceable", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        System.err.println("Found replaceable original text is "+jtf1.getText());
        jtf1.setText(jtf1.getText().substring(0, jtf1.getText().length()-1));
    }
});
```

Comment: Requirements like this boggle my mind. Why do you care how the number is entered into the text area? Let the user determine whether they like to use the keypad or the number keys. Each user is different. Don't limit their options.

Comment: :) I can imagine... I need to do this because I need to read co GS1 code and FNC1 is codified as 18, 95, 95, 96, 105. This means ALT, 0, 0, 2, 9. Now 0029 are not part of the GS1 code, this sequence just marks a field separator and must not be threated as numbers that are part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your String in your textArea to an Array of bytes. After that with a for-loop you should know if there is a number in your textArea. Code numbers begin at 48 (for number zero) and ends at 57 (number 9)

Comment: When I  write to JTextArea I lose the information about the numeric pad. 1 will only have the code 49  even if it originates from num pad and should have the code 97.

Comment: Then can do it with 97 to 105?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `JTextArea#setEditable(false)` method when the numpad key is `pressed` and then `JTextArea#setEditable(true)` when the numpad key is released.

An example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class IgnoreNumpad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
            area.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1, 0, false), "disable");
            area.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2, 0, false), "disable");
            area.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1, 0, true), "enable");
            area.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2, 0, true), "enable");
            //Add all keys
            area.getActionMap().put("disable", new AbstractAction() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    area.setEditable(false); //When key pressed, set it non-editable
                }
            });
            area.getActionMap().put("enable", new AbstractAction() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    area.setEditable(true); //Key released, make it editable
                }
            });
            frame.add(area);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good idea but I don't have this option. The numpad key codes are received when I use a hand held, barcode scanner, the codes are received independent of the num pad status.